# Use regular expression to grab specific tags

Tags: regex

I have a string like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<img src="foo.php?n=bar.jpg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
<img src="somesource.jpg">
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<img src="foo.php?n=bar_2.jpg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<img src="foo.php?n=bar_93.jpg">
```

.
I am now looking for a regex that gives me back all the `<img>` tags where the source contains `bar`

So the output should be:

```
<img src="foo.php?n=bar.jpg">
<img src="foo.php?n=bar_2.jpg">
<img src="foo.php?n=bar_93.jpg">
```

Could anyone help me out please ?

Comment: This can be achieved with simple regex. However I highly advise you to use HTML parser instead.

Comment: I'd use DOM parser with `//img[contains(@src,'bar')]` XPath - much depends on what tool or language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do it

```
<img((bar)|[^>])*?>(?(2)(?=)|(?!))
```

It uses a conditional expression to see if "bar" was matched in group 2